# Install matplotlib to pypy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip, pypy

When I'm trying to install matplotlib using pip it throw me exception:

```
In file included from /usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:26:0,
                 from src/file_compat.h:7,
                 from src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp:3:
/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h: In function ‘int _import_array()’:
/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1686:13: error: ‘NPY_CPU_UNKNOWN_ENDIAN’ was not declared in this scope
   if (st == NPY_CPU_UNKNOWN_ENDIAN) {
             ^
/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1697:13: error: ‘NPY_CPU_LITTLE’ was not declared in this scope
   if (st != NPY_CPU_LITTLE) {
             ^
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vGxrsz/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oB9gVW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vGxrsz/matplotlib
```

If i understand it correctly the problem in numpy. I install it using this command:

`pypy -m pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git@pypy-4.0.1`

My numpy version is 1.9.0. My version of pypy:

```
'2.7.10 (4.0.1+dfsg-1~ppa1~ubuntu15.04, Nov 20 2015, 19:34:27)\n[PyPy 4.0.1 with GCC 4.9.2]'
```

Comment: Numpy is not compatible with PyPy (and neither is matplotlib). See [here](http://packages.pypy.org/) for the list of currently supported packages.

Comment: See e.g. http://morepypy.blogspot.ch/search?q=matplotlib&max-results=20&by-date=true

Comment: @ali_m incorrect. Numpy is compatible.

Comment: @Qix Well, that comment was correct when I wrote it back in February. The situation seems to have improved a bit since then, in that it's now possible to install a full version of numpy using cpyext ([numpypy is far from complete](http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html)). [matplotlib still isn't officially supported](http://packages.pypy.org/##matplotlib) (although see [here](https://morepypy.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/pypy2-v53-released-major-c-extension.html)).

Answer (score 3):

I succeed in install it. (But not perfect)

pypy7.3.3x64 ubuntu WSL

```
pypy3 -m pip install matplotlib==2.2
```

You may need to install some other packages.

[Why 2.2](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7303d81eb2390208d3bac67dd51d390b585e411f/doc/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.2.rst#tkagg-backend-reworked-to-support-pypy)

[image]

[image]

---

Why ipynb? Since GUI on WSL is not so easy. I managed to deal with CPython && matplotlib (By Xming), but not pypy3.

---

Now the newest is mpl==3.3.1, it could work, but with a lot of warning.

```py
/lib/pypy3/lib_pypy/_functools.py:80: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: print_svg() got unexpected keyword argument "orientation" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will become an error two minor releases later
  return self._func(*(self._args + fargs), **fkeywords)
/lib/pypy3/lib_pypy/_functools.py:80: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: savefig() got unexpected keyword argument "orientation" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will become an error two minor releases later
  return self._func(*(self._args + fargs), **fkeywords)
/lib/pypy3/lib_pypy/_functools.py:80: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: savefig() got unexpected keyword argument "dpi" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will become an error two minor releases later
  return self._func(*(self._args + fargs), **fkeywords)
```

Comment: Using WSLg in Windows 11 these days fixes the GUI issues with WSL2.

Answer (score -1):

The fix that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install pypy3-dev
```

Comment: I also wanted to add that matplotlib version 3.5.2 has worked well for me, even on pypy3.10.